# Running WinLogBeat or any Windowds EventLog collector as DaemonSet on Windows nodes in Kuberentes cluster

Tags: windows, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, event-log

Is it possible to be running WinLogBeat or any Windows EventLog collector as DaemonSet on Windows Nodes inside Kubernetes cluster without the need of installing it on every windows pod. All examples are for Linux but there is zero info on how to configure something similar on Windows nodes. Is it even possible to achieve this in theory?

Comment: Probably you can install Winlogbeat as a service on a Windows Node as described [here](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/winlogbeat/docs/getting-started.asciidoc).

Comment: @Orange_times did you solve it? did the above comment help in anyway?

Comment: I didn't find a way to solve it, we installed  windlogbeat as a service inside container